# How do I disable specific form elements in a large form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I must sincerely thank Darren Davies for his help with the following code from which I have made my test html file.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>field_enable</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$().ready(function() {

$('#clicker').click(function() {
$('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('disabled')) {
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr({
            'disabled': 'disabled'
          });
      }
    });
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='clicker' style='background-color:#FF0000; height:20px;     width:50px;'></div>
<br>
<input type='text' disabled></input>
<input type='text' disabled></input>
<input type='text' disabled></input>
</body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly however my form has a large number if fields within which I need to disable only certain one for various clients.  When I apply the code it most certainly activates the fields that I have disabled however it also disables the rest of the fields in the form even though they have no attribute set.  My problem now it to work out how to activate only the fields that I have disabled and leave the rest enabled.

Comment: You just need to take out the else block

Comment: You really need to have better control by using classes on the elements. An element can have multiple classes. Then you can target specific classes based on client. Hunt and peck with generic dom search selectors will be ugly if you don't build some structure into the form that is adaptable to various conditions

Comment: since You are using jQuery. For situations like these rather use .prop(). It is specially for attributes which do not have value like selected and disabled. to to get is it disabled You would write $("selector").prop("disabled") and to disable it $("selector").prop("disabled", true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to affect certain fields you could assign those fields a particular class (changeable in this example)

`<input type='text' disabled class="changeable" />`

and change this line

`$('input').each(function() {`

to

`$('input.changeable').each(function() {`

so that it only works on inputs with the given class

Comment: Hi Dave, this works fine, however I am calling another Class in my form element: class="corners" from my style sheet which adds corners to the text fields.  If I add a disable class="changeble" to the form element I get a conflict and I am not sure how to combine the two classes.  if I remove the corners it works fine but it reduces the appearance of the overall form. Thank - Ivan

Comment: There should not be a problem if you have multiple classes on an element. I dont quite follow where your class assignments are as you are saying form but I think you mean input. Either way it should work. Take a look at this- https://jsfiddle.net/dp3ub0ew/5/ to see that it works. You see it only toggles the inputs with the "changeable" class. (Perhaps you can think of a better name :)

Comment: Thanks Dave, I have worked it out.  You can combine two classes together in one field element.  class="class1 class2".   I still have some work to do but I am now on the right track thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's disabling the other fields because your "if" is telling it to do so. When you use:

```
if ($(this).attr('disabled'))
```

when the input doesn't has this attr, it fails the condition so it will disable the input! :)

What you can do to check is:

```
if ($(this).is("[disabled]") && $(this).attr('disabled')){
  // do your stuff here
}
```

So using elem.is("attr-name") you can know if it has your attr.

Another solution was pointed out by Ivan, you can use classes to diference your inputs.

Cheers